# Python print specific words in colors to output terminal.

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is code I am trying and I need to print green color on terminal if line has pass else Red color if  print line has fail. This is perfectly working using below code.  But I am expecting only pass and fail should print green and red respectively. Not complete line. Please help.

```
HEADER = '\033[95m'
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
BOLD = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
a = [["a", "b", "c", "pass"], ["x", "y", "z", "fail"]]
b = [x for x in a if x is not None]
col_width = max(len(word) for row in b for word in row) + 2  # padding
for row in b:
    if "pass" in row:
        print OKGREEN + ( "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)) + ENDC
    else:
        print FAIL + ( "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)) + ENDC
```

Comment: You might like [crayons](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crayons). Looks more convenient.

Comment: It's doing what you wrote. The color attribute code is written out, then the big string you created, then the reset. You'll need to bracket the single word you want instead.

Comment: [You can use termcolor library. View this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/293633/8381371)

Comment: [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) is another library option. tercolor doesn't work on Windows (Colorama does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the terminal color just before printing the last word in a row (in your case 'pass' or 'fail'), not before printing the whole line:

```
HEADER = '\033[95m'
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
BOLD = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
a = [["a", "b", "c", "pass"], ["x", "y", "z", "fail"]]
b = [x for x in a if x is not None]
col_width = max(len(word) for row in b for word in row) + 2  # padding
for row in b:
    if "pass" in row:
        print "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row[:-1]) + OKGREEN + row[-1] + ENDC
    else:
        print "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row[:-1]) + FAIL + row[-1] + ENDC
```

Comment: "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row[:-2]) + OKGREEN + row[-2] + END..Last one is not printing .i mean it is printing only  a, b c